# How can I expand the evaluation limits for a bivariate seaborn kdeplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to draw a single level of the so-called "iso-proportions" of seaborn's `kdeplot` ([see documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)) on a grid of my choosing. However, the function seems to clip the contour to a grid that it feels is sufficient to characterize the density estimate. Is there any way to force evaluation on a larger grid? Changing the order of where `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` are called does not solve the problem.

Here is an example using samples drawn from a bivariate circular normal distribution.

```
import scipy.stats
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 20000
std_norm_2d = scipy.stats.multivariate_normal(mean=(0,0), seed=42)
samples = std_norm_2d.rvs(size=n, random_state=42)

with mpl.style.context('bmh'):
    plt.figure(dpi=100)
    plt.axis('scaled')
    plt.xlim(-6, 6)
    plt.ylim(-6, 6)
    sns.kdeplot(x=samples[:,0], y=samples[:,1], fill=False, levels=[1e-6])
    plt.show()
```

[image: kdeplot with single contour clipped]

For completeness, here is the output without adjusting the axis scaling or limits.

[image: kdeplot with no axis adjustments]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not particularly obvious, but you can increase the `cut` parameter, which defines how far past the most extreme points the evaluation grid extends (the units correspond to the bandwidth of the smoothing kernel).

e.g.

```
sns.kdeplot(x=samples[:,0], y=samples[:,1], fill=False, levels=[1e-6], cut=10)
```

For your usecase (drawing a single unfilled contour), matplotlib will autoscale the axes correctly. In other situations you may then also want to add `clip` arguments (in data units) to set grid limits.